# How to insert a script after certain paragraphs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a certain ad script which I want to insert after every five paragraphs.
I don't know the way.
I thought this would work but it actually didn't.

```html
<div style="height:50px"></div>

<script async='async' src='https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: Show us the code you tried, and we can help you from there :)

Comment: yes, there is a way : first step => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: on any editor like Visual Studio Code, you can insert any text you want, even the text of your script

Comment: @MisterJojo, Do you know the way to insert ad script after certain paragraphs? Formality isn't important if answer is clear.

Comment: How would you like me to be able to find an answer to a question that is not clear, and that I cannot understand?

Comment: @MisterJojo, I want ads to appear after every five paragraphs. Ad code is above. Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

### Example 1

Takes all the elements `<p>` that are in `#wrap`

After every fifth element adds the code you set in place of `YOUR CONTENT HERE`

```js
var ads = document.createElement("div");
ads.innerHTML = "YOUR CONTENT HERE";

var myWrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
var p = myWrap.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    i = i + 4;
    if (i < p.length) {
        p[i].parentNode.insertBefore(ads.cloneNode(true), p[i].nextSibling);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```

---

### Example 2

This code adds a **Script tag** wrapeed in `div` element after every fifth `<p>` element

*Тhe chance that this code will work with google advertising is minimal.*

If you set the value on `script.src` to a `.js` file that is on your domain this example will work!

```
window.google_ad_client = "123456789";
window.google_ad_slot = "123456789";
window.google_ad_width = 300;
window.google_ad_height = 250;

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js';

///////////////////////////
var ads = document.createElement("div");
ads.appendChild(script);

var myWrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
var p = myWrap.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    i = i + 4;
    if (i < p.length) {
        p[i].parentNode.insertBefore(ads.cloneNode(true), p[i].nextSibling);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do this - uncomment the google ad script when you have changed your id and values

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) {
    const template = document.querySelector('.adsbygoogle');
    const container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.querySelectorAll("div").forEach((div, idx) => {
      if (idx > 0 && idx % 5 === 0) div.after(template.cloneNode(true));
    })
  }
})
```

```css
div >.adsbygoogle {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<!--script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script-->
  <ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:none; width:728px;height:90px" your css
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890123456" your code
    data-ad-slot="1234567890" your value
    >Ad here</ins>
  <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>


<div id="container">
  <div style="height:50px">Div 0
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div style="height:50px">Div 1
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div style="height:50px">Div 2
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div style="height:50px">Div 3
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div style="height:50px">Div 4
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div style="height:50px">Div 5
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div style="height:50px">Div 6
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div style="height:50px">Div 7
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div style="height:50px">Div 8
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div style="height:50px">Div 9
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div style="height:50px">Div 10
    <hr/>
  </div>
  <div style="height:50px">Div 11
    <hr/>
  </div>

</div>
```